# Catch window.open() or target _blank Webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, webview-flutter

I'm currently using [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) for webview appearance. But the problem is I can't find the way to get button tap on webview which is `window.open(url)` or `target="_blank"`.

I want to prevent when it matches above condition.`onNavigationRequest` is provided to prevent but the solution how to get `window.open(url)` or `target="_blank"` is unknown because url is only url string.

```dart
final navigationDelegate = NavigationDelegate(
  onNavigationRequest: (request) {
     final url = request.url; // only url string not window.open() so I can't prevent
   },
);
```

Due to some security I can't use [inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I can catch `window.open()` by using [addJavaScriptChannel](https://pub.dev/documentation/webview_flutter/latest/webview_flutter/WebViewController-class.html). Make a channel in [WebView_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to listen whether you tap on `window.open()`.

```dart
await webViewController.addJavaScriptChannel(
   'callingMethod',
    onMessageReceived: (message) {
        _onMessageReceived(message);
    },
);

final navigationDelegate = NavigationDelegate(
   onPageFinished: (url) => _onPageFinished(url),
);

await webViewController.setNavigationDelegate(navigationDelegate);
```

```dart
Future<void> _onPageFinished(String url) async {
    // Open here is window.open() on JS
    // Make javascript including catch window.open() and channel
    await webViewController.runJavaScript('''
       open = (str) => { nativeMethod.postMessage("open=" + str); };
       var Android = {
           callingMethod: (str) => {
            callingMethod.postMessage(str);
       }
    };
    ''');

Future<void> _onMessageReceived(JavaScriptMessage message) async {
    String key = message.message.substring(0, message.message.indexOf("="));
    String value = message.message.substring(message.message.indexOf("=") + 1);

    if (key == "open") {
      // do something
    }
  }
```